# Why error is not returned by Error constructor?

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
Future<FlutterError> foo() async => FlutterError('Error');

void main() {
  foo().then(print).catchError(print);
}
```

I'm returning `Error` from `foo` method and instead of `catchError`, `then` is executed. So, why an error being an `Error` isn't caught in the `catchError`?

**Note**: I'm not looking for how to make it work, I know you can use `throw` instead of returning the error.

Comment: Why wouldn't the `.then()` callback be executed?  No exception is thrown, so there's nothing to catch.

Comment: @jamesdlin Are errors from an `async` function not supposed to be caught in `catchError`?

Comment: They are, but returning a value (regardless of its type) from an `async` function isn't an erroneous state.  The `async` keyword enables some automatic transformations on the function, such as making `return` statements complete `Future`s successfully and `throw` statements complete `Future`s with an error.  If a function is marked as `async`, errors are expected be thrown.

Comment: Or, in other words: `catchError` catches *thrown* errors (or other objects).

Comment: @lrn But sir, `catchError` also catches *returned* errors, `Future<void> f() => Future.error('e')`. I think we shouldn't allow `throw`ing a `Future.error`, it really makes no sense.

Comment: @iDecode That's not a returned future, it just looks like one. The future is *not* returned, it's just that returns in `async` functions have an implicit `await` when you are returning a `Future<X>` where `X` is assignable to the actual future return type.. So, returning a `Future.error('e')` is treated as returning `await Future.error('e')`, which raises the error instead of returning the future. On the other hand, you can throw *any* object, so you can `throw Future.error('e')` and that future is the actual object being throw. 
I recommend awaiting all futures, and not return or throw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused in how `Future` work and how errors are identified as errors. It is not an error to return an object which inherit from `Error` or `Exception`. So what you are doing is creating a normal object (in this case `FlutterError`) and returns it inside a `async` marked method which are then converting it into `Future<FlutterError>`.

You should instead `throw` the exception/error if you want your `async` method to return a `Future` which is marked as failed.

Alternative, we can return a `Future` which has already failed (e.g. by using `Future.error`). This instance will then be seen as a failed `Future` and therefore triggers the `catchError` method.

Comment: Instead of `FlutterError`, if you use `Future.error`, the `catchError` works.

Comment: @iDecode Yes, see my last added part of my answer. `Future.error` is a `Future` which is marked as failed. If you return (not throw) this instance, it will be seen as a failed `Future` which triggers `catchError`.

Comment: @iDecode Ok, I have added more text to my answer. :)